# I want the function to take input and process it-- python code

Tags: python

output "for this code is Process finished with exit code 0" but I want it to be as either true or false

```
def is_tri(p,q,r):   # function to lengths values of triangle
    if(p>(q+r)):
        return "False"
    elif(q>(p+r)):
        return "False"
    elif(r>(p+q)):
        return "False"
    else:
        return "True"

p = int(input("Enter first side length: "))
q = int(input("Enter second side length: "))
r = int(input("Enter`enter code here` third side length: "))
is_tri(p,q,r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exit code `0` means that process has finished without error. Status can be only integer, anything else than `0` means something went wrong. In order to print `True` or `False` do the following:

```
print(is_tri(p, q, r))
```

Comment: ThanQ for your help. I got it